# Can a project that is being built with JDK target=8 consume a library built with JDK target=11 in JRE 11?

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Can a project compiled with JDK-8 consume a library built with JDK-11, while running on JRE 11?

Furthermore, can a project compiled with JDK-11, consume a library built with JDK-8, while running on JRE 11?

I tried the scenario with compiling to JDK-11, consume a library built with JDK-8, while running on JRE 11 and there were no issues

Comment: Have you tried the first scenario too?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes.